# Using PATINDEX to verify and replace

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that converts float to string with pre-assigned len and precision and removes trailing and leading zeroes.

```
SELECT 
replace(ltrim(replace(replace(rtrim(replace(str(2005.012, 17,9), '0', ' ')), ' ','0'),'0',' ')), ' ','0')
```

**Output:**

```
2005.012
```

But the issue with this query is if I have a data 0.0 It's returning just a decimal.

```
SELECT 
replace(ltrim(replace(replace(rtrim(replace(str(0.0, 17,9), '0', ' ')), ' ','0'),'0',' ')), ' ','0')
```

**Output**:

```
.
```

Is there a way I can use patindex to check if the output is "." then replace it with 0.0?
Or any other way to remove leading and trailing zero **without using cast or round** (its messing up with the decimal precision as I'm comparing data from 2 database its not an option for me).

Any idea or help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: what is wrong with using `cast` or `convert` ?

Comment: I need the exact return as I m going to concat multiple columns and then validate the data from backup/another database it needs to be exactly the same.

Comment: First of all, what *is* your input type? `2005.012` is a `DECIMAL`, not a `FLOAT`. Using `STR` will implicitly convert it to one, but it's much more important to know what your actual input *is*. It's probable that instead of the complicated dance you're doing now something much simpler can suffice, like `FORMAT`.

Comment: `Format(<cast as decimal value>, '0.#########')` ?

Comment: Input is always going to float in this case.

Comment: If I have column1 with 1634.31005859375 in snowflake db, sql db.

And I need to verify that column if I do Format(column1, '0.#########') it rounds up the remaining digits and returns 1634.3100586 in SQL which not going to match with the data in snowflake and hence the code will throw an error.
Also, I m just using the example for 1 column in general i m doing concat of all the column values and then comparing with concat of snowflake column.

Comment: Everything is fine except if data is 0.0 is returning "." with the query below and I need to fix that only.

SELECT replace(ltrim(replace(replace(rtrim(replace(str(2005.012, 17,9), '0', ' ')), ' ','0'),'0',' ')), ' ','0')

Comment: So why not just add another nesting level to return '0.0' literal string if value = '.' ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that.
So basically you are saying if the value == '.' then return '0.0' if yes. Is it possible to implement this query? If i replace(col, ".',"0") in it wont it make the other "." 0 as well.. like 202.5 will return as 20205? I m new to this sorry if i miss understood you.

SELECT replace(ltrim(replace(replace(rtrim(replace(str(0.0, 17,9), '0', ' ')), ' ','0'),'0',' ')), ' ','0')

Comment: Snowflake's `FLOAT` should be the same as SQL Server's `FLOAT`, as in, they have the same precision. On the SQL Server end `FORMAT` can be used to generate any desired precision (e.g. `SELECT FORMAT(1634.31005859375e, 'G17')`), on the Snowflake end I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement something like the following that just expands on your current string-replace solution:

```
with n as ( /* sample data */
    select str(2005.182, 17,9) [value] union all 
    select Str(0.0, 17,9)
)

select Iif(v = '.', '0.0', v) Result
from n
cross apply (values(replace(ltrim(replace(replace(rtrim(replace([value], '0', ' ')), ' ','0'),'0',' ')), ' ','0')))v(v);
```

Comment: This is awesome! 
One question in this is if I have to concat multiple columns using this way.. how can I add that?

SELECT CONCAT(yourquery, yourquery) is giving error.

Comment: This sounds like a new question, I'm not sure what you mean or what "giving error" means.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, something like this works pretty well, without the need to replace strings (though less intuitive, I suppose):

```
SELECT  STR(Test.FloatVal, 17, CONVERT(INT, FLOOR(LOG10(REVERSE(ABS(CONVERT(DECIMAL(17, 9), Test.FloatVal) * 10) + 1)) + '1') + 1))
FROM    (
            VALUES (CONVERT(FLOAT, 2005.0125))
            ,      (CONVERT(FLOAT, 0.0))
            ,       (CONVERT(FLOAT, -2005.0125))
            ,       (CONVERT(FLOAT, 00090009))
            ,       (CONVERT(FLOAT, 123123.12310000))
        ) AS Test (FloatVal)
```

This gives:

```
+-------------+
|   2005.0125 |
|         0.0 |
|  -2005.0125 |
|     90009.0 |
| 123123.1231 |
+-------------+
```